# How is CLion terminating a process runing?

Tags: c++, signals, clion

I am working on a TCP server that I'm developing on CLion under Windows 10.

I would like my program to be able to end properly, when I click on "stop" my program. I thought CLion was sending a signal, but after trying to catch them all, it looks like it does not.

So my question is, how does CLion stop running the program? Is it possible to detect it within the program?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you debugging the program? Debuggers have low-level godly powers. If they want the program they're running to die, it dies.

Comment: No, I am not even debugging. I didn't know about these "low-level godly powers" that debuggers have though ahah!

Comment: @user4581301 beyond sending a signal (like `SIGTERM` (which you can catch) or `SIGKILL` (which you cannot catch)), could you please elaborate on those "godly powers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-tool-window.html).

According to this link, signals are actually used :

> Click this button to terminate the current process externally by means
>   of the standard shutdown script. Clicking the button once invokes soft
>   kill allowing the application to catch the SIGINT event and perform
>   graceful termination (on Windows, the Ctrl+C event is emulated). After
>   the button is clicked once, it is replaced with icon run tool window
>   kill indicating that subsequent click will lead to force termination
>   of the application, e.g. on Unix SIGKILL is sent.